# Tracing this file

Tags: c

```
int f(int x, int y)
{
    int u;
    u = x*y;
    printf("in f\n");

    return( x+u+y );
}

int g(int* p, int* q)
{
    int v;
    v = *p + *q;
    printf("in g, before f\n");

    *q = f(v, *p);
    printf("in g, after f\n");

    return( v-*q );
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

    printf("in main, before f and g\n");

    a = f(a, b);
    b = g(&b, &c);

    printf("in main, after f and g\n");

    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm having a real hard time trying to trace this file cause I'm getting lost in regards to getting the addresses of b and c. And as well as the pointers .-. Can anyone help explain by tracing this code cause I'm totally lost.

Comment: Please edit the post and then indent the code properly. Then explain what you understood, and where do exactly do you have the problem.

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? if you need addresses of b and c then &b and &c can give you that on displaying using printf("%u %u",&b,&c)

Comment: What do you mean by "tracing"?

Answer (score 1):

If you would run the code through a debugger you would see what happens with each variable and each address. Outputting the addresses of each of the variable will give you very little information since the addresses will most likely change with each execution.

Instead, use a pen and paper and figure out yourself what happens. I'll give you an example based on your code.

These are the starting values in `main()` for the variables :

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
```

Now the function `f()` is called which doesn't use pointers so the value of each variable is copied in the function's parameters. The return value of `f(a,b)` is assigned to `a` in `main()` so now the values of the variables become :

```
a   b   c
5   2   3
```

Now the addresses of `b` and `c` are passed to `g(p,q)`. In `g()` a local variable `v` becomes the sum of the contents of pointers `p` and `q` which are the values of `b` and `c`.

```
*p  *q  v
2   3   5
```

Now the contents of `q` gets changed by a call to `f()` which doesn't use pointers and only the values of `v` and the contents of `p` are passed as arguments. `f()` returns 17. So now the contents of `q` (which is the value of `b`) becomes 17.

```
*p  *q  v
2   17  5
```

Now the function `g()` returns the value of the difference between the value of `v` and the contents of `q` (which is the value of `c`).

In `main()` the value returned by `g()` is -12 and it's assigned to b. So now our variables have the values :

```
a   b   c
5   -12 17
```

Note that `c` kept the value of 17 from the function `g()` because it was modified via a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

1. See on the function call the values are going to get passed and and in the second the
   address is going to get passed, which means first one is call by value and other is by 
   reference, in `a=f(a,b);`
2. So the value getting stored in a after return is `1+2+2 = 5`. Now since `a` and `b` are local variables `a=5`, `b=2`.
3. Now on function call `b=g(&a,&b);`
4. The address is passed and the pointer is used to extract the value stored at that address. Simply calling and the value is going to be modified at the address of the passed parameters according to the computation, no change in address is thr, you can still print thr address by using the `&` operator to check yourself.